# A thinks of card - B pick card from pack - they are the same - what odds

Tags: probability

"A" thinks of any card in a pack and "B" selects a card from a faced down pack - what are the odds against them being the same. I only have low level maths - so be nice please. Thanks

Comment: There are $52$ equally likely possibilities and $51$ of them are wrong, so $\frac {51}{52}$.

Comment: To be clear:  what I wrote is the probability that the guess is wrong.  You asked for "the odds" which, technically, isn't the same as probability.  Odds of $1:1$ correspond to a $\frac 12$ probability for example.  Did you mean odds?  If so, the odds are given by $51:1$.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what card A is thinking of, or even with what probability A is thinking of certain cards. In fact, A could simply say out loud what card A is thinking of, or even always think of the exact same card: given that B chooses a card at random, we are simply looking for the probability that the 1 card that B randomly picks does not match some specific card.

And given that B picks the card at random, the probability that this card is the card we are looking for is $\frac{1}{52}$, and so the probability that the card does not match the card we are looking for is $$1-\frac{1}{52}=\frac{51}{52}$$ assuming a standard deck of 52 playing cards. Or, in terms of odds: the odds are $51 : 1$ against $B$ picking the same card $A$ is thinking of.

Comment: Nice answer +1, Also, It would be better if you present your answer as odds against , instead of probability notation.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that.